# Cant install TeeChart in VS2022 WebForms .NET framework?

Tags: .net, teechart, visual-studio-2022

Ok this is driving me mad now.
Ive used TeeChart in many desktop app but it seems impossible to get installed in a webApp using .NET Framework.

Every NuGet package seems to be for .NET Core only.
When a NuGet package is installed no items appear in the toolbox, when manually added and added to a form there is instantly a license error issue even if just in evaluation mode?

(Seems to be wrong ctl type added to te form me thinks)

Anyone else got this issue and any ideas on how to resolve?

Cheers

Comment: If you have a Pro license, the NuGet to use is this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/Steema.TeeChart.NET/ With a Business license, it's this one https://www.nuget.org/packages/Steema.TeeChart.NET.Business/

Comment: Check if there's a TeeChart license line in licenses.licx (if it exists) and remove it.